# When a change is done on data on a viewUI, it doesn't appear in the others. Only when re-launching the app it's fine in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm building an app to keep track of a collection. The data have been preloaded in the app via a JSON file that it's then decoded. To make it possible to say wether the user has a specific item, I added a button in every item in the swiftUI. Here is the example:
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlOVz.jpg)

To keep it simple i added the tab 'Collection' to filter only items that the user has toggled in the other page
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fpfg.jpg)

My problem is that when i toggle a item in the firstUI, it doesnt update the collection view. But if i re-launch the app everything is correct. It looks like the list of 'favorites' items is update only once, when launching the app. it's not updated costanlty. How can i solve it?

This is the class favorites that keep track of the owned items:

```
import Foundation

class Favorites: ObservableObject {
    

    private var minifigs: Set<String>
    
    private let saveKey = "Favorites"
    
   
    
    init() {
        self.minifigs = Set((UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: saveKey) as? [String]) ?? [])
    }
    func contains(_ minifig: Minifig) -> Bool {
        minifigs.contains(minifig.id)
    }
    func notContains(_ minifig: Minifig) -> Bool {
        !(minifigs.contains(minifig.id))
    }
    func add(_ minifig: Minifig) {
        objectWillChange.send()
        minifigs.insert(minifig.id)
        save()
    }
    func remove(_ minifig: Minifig) {
        objectWillChange.send()
        minifigs.remove(minifig.id)
        save()
    }
    func save(){
        
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(Array(minifigs), forKey: saveKey)
        
    }
    
}
```

While this is the ViewUI of the 'collection' tab, the one i want to be updated costantly:

```
import SwiftUI



struct OwnedView: View {
    
    let minifigs: [Minifig] = Bundle.main.decode("minifigures.json")
    @StateObject var favorites = Favorites()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
        
        List {
            Text("You have \(minifigs.filter(favorites.contains).count) out of \(minifigs.count) minifigures")
                .font(.headline)
            ForEach(minifigs.filter(favorites.contains)) { minifig in
                
                HStack {
                    VStack{
                        Text(minifig.name)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .frame(width: 180, height: 10)
                        Text("\(minifig.series) • \(minifig.number)")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Image("Series\(minifig.id)")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                    
                }
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(favorites)
        .navigationTitle("Your Minifigures:")
        .refreshable {
            
        }
    }
}

}   
    struct OwnedView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            OwnedView()
        }
        
    }
```

I think the problem cuold be related to the @StateObject... I don't know

Comment: Try `@Published var minifigs: Set<String>` in your Favorites class

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it still doesn't work, unfortunately...

Comment: It seems that your code has multiple issues. Please try to add a [mre] so we can understand what you are doing here. In particular how does the `other View` hold the `Favorites` class?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from your code, it looks like you are not using the same instance of `Favorites` in the two views, thus producing this incongruence.

What you should aim for is having only one instance of `Favorites` in your app; you can achieve that by instantiating the object in a root view and then injecting the object through bindings or environment objects.

Since you have a `TabBar` you can instantiate it in there as `StateObject`:

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
    
    @StateObject
    private var favourites = Favourites()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ViewA()
                .environmentObject(favourites)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("a")
                }
            
            ViewB()
                .environmentObject(favourites)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("b")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I would recommend having your `var minifigs` as `Published` since a change of it will trigger a view update